# HTTP status codes for file uploading in PHP

Tags: php, rest, http, post, upload

I'm trying to develop a REST-like PHP script able to accept a POST request to upload files. I need to define the HTTP request and response syntax, beside the HTTP standard of course.

I'm trying to find the best HTTP status codes corresponding to each possible PHP error. You'll see what I found so far below.

I'm not entirely sure of all of them (I'm open to suggestions), but my biggest concern is that they match only if one file was uploaded.

How do I manage multiple file uploading?

The problem remains if the upload is atomic or if it isn't (if an error on one file cancel the entire upload or if it doesn't).

---

- `$_FILES[]['error']`:

  - `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`: 413 (too big)
  - `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE`: 413 (too big)
  - `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL`: 409 (try again)
  - `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE`: 204 (no file in request, nothing to do)
  - `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR`: 500 (conf' problem)
  - `UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE`:

    - `!is_writable()`: 500 (temp dir not writable)
    - `$_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE'] > disk_free_space()`: 507 (not enough space in temp dir)
    - 500 (unknown server problem while writing temp file)
  - `UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION`: 409 (try again, maybe stopped by user)
  - `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`:

    - `!is_uploaded_file($_FILES[]['tmp_name'])`:
      500 (file at `TMPDIR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$_FILES[]['tmp_name']` wasn't actually downloaded, maybe a problem with temp dir path case)
    - `!is_writable()`: 500 (target dir not writable)
    - `$_FILES[]['size'] > disk_free_space()`: 507 (not enough space in target dir)
    - `file_exists()`: 409 (try again, file name is prefixed with timestamp in target dir)
    - `!move_uploaded_file()`: 500 (unknown server error while moving uploaded file)
    - 201 (file successfully uploaded)

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here: http://racksburg.com/choosing-an-http-status-code/

Comment: Well that's your choice, really.  (Though personally, I'd class `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` as a 400, since it usually means the client did something wrong.)

Comment: @DaSourcerer Thanks! Not enough but it does help.

Comment: @Joe C Well, it pops out when you submit without selecting any file, so it may not be an error.